Copying text from HTML Editor in Rich Text
I have a Flutter Web app and I have a HTML string which I am rendering using html_editor_enhanced. When I highlight the text and press CTRL+C on my keyboard, I can paste it into my Gmail and it appears with all the formatting in place, like Rich Text. However, when I use the HtmlEditorController to get the text (_htmlEditorController.getText()) and then store it in the Clipboard (await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: rawHtml))), it returns all the raw HTML, including tags. When I paste it into Gmail, it's just the raw HTML with no formatting.
How can I imitate what the standard copy (CTRL+C) does in code, so I can paste it into Gmail and maintain the formatting?

The standard Clipboard class appears to not have mime labelling of clipboard content, so I imagine all your HTML is becoming flat text.
Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/super_clipboard which purports to solve this mime-type labelling.

Thanks for this. I had assumed the issue was with getting the data from the HTML widget, rather than storing it in the clipboard. Super clipboard does the trick!
